# Cpanel update feed or WHM update notifications

Tags: cpanel, whm

the latest cpanel update caused a couple of issues on some of our servers, a reboot fixed them but we'd really like to put something in place to monitor updates.

Does anyone know of a feed of cpanel updates thats kept as up-to-date as their releases? Or is there a way to get WHM to email me when updates are run? I couldnt find anything in the notifications section.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

NO, There is no way to setup the notification of cPanel update releases. But I will suggest you please chnage your cPanel update preferences to "**STABLE**" so that you will not get any issues due to cPanel upadtes. You can chnage this through **WHM >> Server Configuration >> Update Preferences**